# Is $f\mapsto\int f^{-1}d\mu$ a weak-* continuous functional on $\{f\in L^\infty(\mu):\alpha\le f\le \beta\}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, weak-convergence

**Problem Setting.** Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on some space $\Omega$. Consider the subset of $L^\infty(\mu)$ defined by $S=\{f\in L^\infty(\mu):\alpha\le f\le \beta\}$, where $\alpha\le\beta$ are positive constants. Identify $L^\infty(\mu)$ with the continuous dual of $L^1(\mu)$.

My question: is the functional $f\mapsto\int \frac{1}{f}d\mu$ weak-* continuous on $S$?

---

**Additional Material.**
I'm trying to fill in the gaps of Talagrand's one-paragraph proof of the following inequality:

> Assume $g$ is a measurable function on $\Omega$ satisfying $e^{-t}\le g(\omega)\le 1$ for some $t>0$. Then 
>   \begin{align}\int \frac1gd\mu\int gd\mu\le\frac12+\frac{e^{-t}+e^t}{4}.
> \end{align}

The proof goes as fixing $\int gd\mu$ and optimizing the convex functional $g\mapsto\int g^{-1}d\mu$, claiming that it attains its maximum at some extreme point of $S$. Of course, a standard result following from Krein-Milman says that continuous convex functional on a compact convex set attains its minimum at some extreme points. For our case, $S$ is weak-* compact by Banach-Alaoglu theorem, so it remains to show that the convex functional of interest is weak-* continuous, which resisted several of my attempts.

I appreciate any answer to my question or an alternative way to fill in the gaps in Talagrand's proof.

Comment: For those who may concern: the proof appears in [one of Talagrand's prominent papers](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02699376) as an elementary lemma.

Answer (score 2):

The functional is not weak-$*$ continuous.

Consider the example with $\Omega=(0,1)$, $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure,
$\alpha=1,\beta=2$.
We define the sequence
$$
f_n = 1+\chi_{A_n}
\quad \text{with} \quad
A_n = \{\omega\in\Omega : sin(2\pi n \omega)>0\}.
$$
Then it is possible to show that
$f_n$ converges weakly-$*$ to $f_0:=3/2$.
However, for the function values we have
$$
\int \frac1{f_n} \mathrm d\mu
= \tfrac12+\tfrac12\cdot\tfrac12=\tfrac34
$$
and
$$
\int\frac1{f_0}\mathrm d\mu
= \tfrac23\neq\tfrac34.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the nice counterexample!